# Controlling reducer shuffle merge memory in Hadoop 2

Tags: hadoop

I want understand how memory is used in the reduce phase of a MapReduce Job, so I can control the settings in the designated way.

If I understand correctly, the reducer first **fetches** its map output and leaves them in memory up to a certain threshold. The settings to control this are:

- [mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.merge.percent](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml): The usage threshold at which an in-memory merge will be initiated, expressed as a percentage of the total memory allocated to storing in-memory map outputs, as defined by mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.input.buffer.percent.
- [mapreduce.reduce.input.buffer.percent](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml): The percentage of memory- relative to the maximum heap size- to retain **map outputs** during the reduce. When the shuffle is concluded, any remaining map outputs in memory must consume less than this threshold before the reduce can begin.

Next, these spilled blocks are **merged**. It seems the following option controls how much memory is used for the shuffle:

- [mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.input.buffer.percent](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml): The percentage of memory to be allocated from the maximum heap size to storing map outputs during the shuffle.

But then, there is the setting:

- [mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.memory.limit.percent](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml): Maximum percentage of the in-memory limit that a single shuffle can consume.

But it is not clear to what value this percentage applies. **Is there more information available regarding these values, i.e. what they control and how they differ?**

Finally, after the merge completes, the reduce process is ran on the inputs. In the [Hadoop book][1], I found that the final merge-step directly feeds the reducers. But, the default value for mapreduce.reduce.input.buffer.percent=0 contradicts this, indicating that everything is spilled to disk BEFORE the reducers start. **Is there any reference on which one of these explanations is correct?**

[1]: Hadoop, The definitive guide, Fourth edition, p. 200

Answer (score 0):

Here is how mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.memory.limit.percent is used and its percentage implies a 0.70 percent of the whole reducer memory. That would be the maximum bytes upto which the data could be kept in memory for a **single shuffle**.

```
maxSingleShuffleLimit = (long)(maxSize * MAX_SINGLE_SHUFFLE_SEGMENT_FRACTION);
//MAX_SINGLE_SHUFFLE_SEGMENT_FRACTION=mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.memory.limit.percent(0.25 f)
maxSize = (int)(conf.getInt("mapred.job.reduce.total.mem.bytes",(int)Math.min(Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory(), Integer.MAX_VALUE))* maxInMemCopyUse);//maxInMemCopyuse(mapred.job.shuffle.input.buffer.percent - 0.70f)
```

This property is used in the copy phase of the reducer. If the required map output is greater than the maxShufflelimit then the data is moved to disk,else kept in memory.

Property `mapreduce.reduce.input.buffer.percent` is completety different. 
Once all the data is copied and all the merge is done, just before the reducer starts it just checks whether the data stored in memory exceeds this limit.

You could refer [this](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.ning/metrics.action/0.2.0/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/ReduceTask.java#ReduceTask.ReduceCopier.ShuffleRamManager.0MAX_SINGLE_SHUFFLE_SEGMENT_FRACTION) code(however it is for old mapred it should give an insight) on how maxSingleShuffleLimit and the other property are used.

Comment: thanks for the explanation and reference! But mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.merge.percent should determine the threshold in the copy phase? Of is this different?

Comment: Also, what is exactly a **single shuffle**?

Comment: When all the inputs are being copied from map side to reduce side, a merge phase will also begin.So mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.merge.percent would tell the percent of memory till which the data can be kept in memory during that merge phase.

Comment: Map outputs are copied as when it is available. So lets assume we have 2 mappers and reducers are also set to 2, now we could get 2 partitions of data from each mapper. If mapper 1 completes well before Mapper 2 then that map1 output would be copied into the buffer. Now this is a single shuffle.

Comment: if I understand correctly: the mapreduce.reduce.shuffle options are both for the copy and the merge phase, i.e., the amount of memory required for receiving data is .input.buffer.percent. The collected map outputs are sent to disk when memory.limit.percent is exceeded, but this has nothing to do with merging. shuffle.merge.percent is then used to indicate when the map output data should start being merged. Is this correct? But then, how do you indicate the amount of memory that can be used for doing the subsequent merge-sort phases? Or is the same amount used?

Comment: Yep you are right. For the last point there is no separate sort phase in reducer side, the sorting is already done in map side. From the definitive guide "When all the map outputs have been copied the reduce task moves into the sort phase(which should properly called the merge phase as the sorting was carried out on the map side), which merges the map outputs, maintaining their sort order". For merging it uses mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.merge.percent to hold the data in memory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90035/discussion-between-xaero182-and-vignesh-i).